# Web scraping automation tool using Python and Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, automation

I'm trying to implement a program that reads text every 10 minutes from a weather database website and converts text to speech to provide updates. But every time I request updates from the website the data remains unchanged as it was at the start of the loop and the updates do not change as the page refreshes. For example, the temperature remains the same as the start of the loop even though I am using a web scraping tool every time the loop is executed(every 10 minutes loop is executed).

```
for i in range(n):  //for-loop to keep updating it for 'n' number of times 

 import requests
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  //web-scraping using beautifulsoup
 from urllib.request import urlopen
 import pyttsx3
 text_speech = pyttsx3.init()
 import time    
 import bs4







 headers = {
'User-Agent':"Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.61 Mobile Safari/537.36 Edg/94.0.992.31'"}

 url = "https://www.bbc.com/weather/your-city-id" //Enter the weather link of the city that needs to be checked   
 t = time.localtime()
 current_hr = time.strftime("%H:%M", t)
 text_speech.say(current_hr)   //tells-current-time
 text_speech.runAndWait()
 cnt5=''
 cnt6=''
 cnt1 =''
 r = requests.get(url,{'headers':headers})
 soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text,"html.parser")
 tag = soup.find('h1', attrs={"id": "wr-location-name-id"})
 cnt1+=tag.text
 tag = soup.find('span', attrs={"class": "wr-value--temperature--c"})
 cnt5+=tag.text
 tag = soup.find('div', attrs={"class": "wr-day__weather-type-description wr-js-day-content- 
 weather-type-description wr-day__content__weather-type-description--opaque"})
 cnt6+=tag.text
 final = "The   temperature is "+ cnt5 + "  now"
 text_speech.say(cnt1)   //text-to-speech
 text_speech.runAndWait() 
 text_speech.say(final)
 text_speech.runAndWait()
 text_speech.say(cnt6)
 text_speech.runAndWait()
 print(current_hr)
 time.sleep(600)  //should refresh every 10 minutes
```

Comment: Before all, replace the `//` by the valid python comments `#` , and also, remove the import from your loop. PS : and check you indentation

Comment: I added the comments only for the purpose of posting this question, and I don't think there is an issue with the indentation as there were no errors while executing.

Comment: For a start, I suggest you move all the `import` statements to the top, outside of your loop. That only needs to be done once.

Comment: Do you see a difference between what you hear and what you see if you view the same page on your browser? Perhaps also print what you "say" so you can see any changes. I am not sure how often the page itself changes (perhaps hourly?)

Comment: Yes the loop prints out the time for every iteration so, it is sure that the loop is working properly. I have tried printing it out and it returns the same. The page refreshes every hour(I think) but the temperature need not be different every time the page refreshes.

Comment: I meant if you load the page in a browser, is it giving different results? And the BBC website might not update all that often. The script seems fine. Another approach might be to poll more often e.g. 10minutes, and then compare with the previous data and then only speak if different.